# Best way for setting parameter types in C#

Tags: c#, enums, parameters, settings

I have an implementation concern about how best to set parameters within C#. I normally use enums , such as.

```
 namespace ConsoleApp1

{
    public enum CarBrand
    {
        Renault,
        Fiat,
        Peugeot
    }

    public enum Peugeot
    {
        Pegout308, 
        Pegout208,
        Pegout3008
    }

    public enum Fiat
    {
        Panda,
        Fiat500
    }

    public enum Renault
    {
        Clio,
        Captur,
        Kangoo
    }
}
```

Instead, I would like to find a functional way to have the parameters set in the following way:

```
CarBrand.Peugeot.Pegout208
```

or

```
CarBrand.Renault.Captur
```

Comment: What about static properties? Assuming that `Peugot208` is supposed to be an instance of a class.

Comment: Does it has to be enum? I could think of enum-like classes. `CarBrand` would hold static properties of all brands. Each brand - properties of all its cars, etc.

Comment: I am open to all best solution and not locked on enum. Do you suggest to create 4 classes? where class CarBrand holds the 3 bands?

Comment: See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CD2lKY).

Comment: As already Sinatr and imsmn suggested you can use static properties, but before that we need to know the use case, for example, if you are going to save data to database enums are really bad for this case, and static properties are not good either and you need to have 2 tables (for Car Brand and Model) in database. first, we need to know what you are trying to achieve.